# Fachbegriff für Lehnwörter aus dem Japanischen u.a

Tags: terminology, loanword

Fast jeder kennt ***Anglizismus*** für Lehnwörter aus dem Englischen. 
Auch 
***Gräzismus*** (griechisch), 
***Romanismus*** (romanisch) oder *Latinismus* (lateinisch), 
***Gallizismus*** (französisch) und 
***Hispanismus*** (spanisch)
sind für die Hauptquellen des deutschen Fremdwortschatzes zumindest fachsprachlich hinreichend etabliert. 
Als Oberbegriff eignet sich ***Xenismus***, auch wenn das Wort nicht besonders etabliert ist.
Wie steht es mit den historisch weniger einflussreichen Herkunftssprachen?

- Sind *Grenze* und *Roboter* einfach ***Slawismen*** bzw. ***Slavismen*** oder gibt es hinreichend gut erkennbare Begriffe für polnische, tschechische, sorbische ... Herkunft?
- Ist das ungarische *Gulasch* ein ***Magyarismus***?
- Kann man die norwegischen *Ski* und *Fjord* als ***Skandinavismen***, ***(Nord-)Germanismen*** oder gar ***Nordismen*** bezeichnen?
- Sind *Sushi*, *Tsunami*, *Karaoke*, *Anime*, *Manga*, *Hentai*, *Bukkake* oder *Emoji* nun ***Nipponismen***, ***Nihonismen***, ***Japanismen*** oder noch was anderes? (Das ist meine hauptsächliche Frage.)
- Mir fällt gerade kein Beispiel für einen ***Sinismus***, ***Sinoismus*** oder ***Sinozismus*** aus der chinesischen Makrosprache ein.

Für Eigenheiten der (großen) deutschen Regionalsprachen gibt es daneben Begriffe wie *Teutonismus*, *Austriazismus*, *Helvetismus*.

Comment: Die Wurzel "robot-" ist den slawischen Sprachen gemein für Dinge, die mit Arbeit zu tun haben. (Bulgarisch работа: Arbeit, um mal ein südslavisches Beispiel zu nehmen). Die Prägung "Roboter" kam zwar von irgend einem Schriftsteller meine ich... aus dem Tschechischen? Ich würde hier aber schon von einem  Slavismus sprechen.

Comment: Austriazismus: gut. Aber wie würden Übernahmen aus der Sprache ihrer nordwestlichen Nachbarn heißen: Schwabizismen? Suabizismen?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann 1920, [Josef Čapek](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Čapek).

Comment: Warum muss es dafür ein Fachwort geben? "Japanisches Lehnwort" beschreibt es doch sehr gut.

Comment: Ist denn Anglizismus und Lehnwort das gleiche? [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglizismus) beschreibt das meines Erachtens so, dass der Anglizismus die Vorstufe eines Lehnworts ist.

Comment: @dirkt Und beschreibt etwa *Spanisches Lehnwort* nicht genau so gut *Hispanismus*? Jedoch gibt es den Begriff.

Comment: @dirkt Es *muss* dafür keinen Fachbegriff geben. Ich frage, ob es einen gibt und ggf. welchen. Ich finde es stilistisch schöner, bspw. von „Gräzismen und Romanismen“ schreiben zu können, als von „Anglizismen und spanischen Fremdwörtern“.

Comment: Leider ist der [Japonismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japonismus) schon anderweitig belegt. ;)

Comment: Man kann genauso "englische und spanische Lehnwörter" schreiben. Übrigens hat zumindest Anglizismus eine weitergehende Bedeutung: Verwendung eines meist nicht eingedeutschten Fremdwortes oder Ausdrucks anstelle des vorhandenen deutschen Begriffes. *Sushi*, *Karaoke*, *Anime* sind in diesem Sinne keine Äquivalente von Anglizismen wie *coffee to go* oder *Showmaster*.

Comment: @dirkt Ich dachte, das nennten die Sprachnörgler _Denglisch_. (Das bezeichnet natürlich eigentlich eine bestimmte Motorradfahrweise. _Beinhart wie 'n Rocker!_) Ein Anglizismus kann Fremdwort, Lehnwort, Fachwort, ... sein und nicht in jedem Kontext würde ich mich auf eines davon festlegen müssen wollen.

Comment: Ich sagte "eine weitergehende Bedeutung". Man kann es auch Denglisch nennen, aber bei Ausdrücken wie "*das macht Sinn* ist ein Anglizismus" ist recht klar, welche Variante gemeint ist.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehnwort#Entlehnungen_im_Deutschen) benutzt für viele Sprachen solche Begriffe, neben _Japanismus_ und _Sinismus_ z.B. auch noch _Polonismus_, _Hungarismus_ und _Fennizismus_. Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, inwieweit diese Begriffe wirklich geläufig sind (zumindest in der jeweiligen Fachdomäne) oder eher Konstruktionen der jeweiligen WP-Autoren.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Der Begriff *Roboter* wird üblicherweise eng mit dem polnischen Schriftsteller Stanislav Lem verbunden, der sich mit seinen "Robotergesetzen" als erster intensiv in mehreren seiner Romane literarisch mit dem Thema auseinandergesetzt hat. Zuerst *verwendet* wurde der Begriff *robot* allerdings wohl von https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Čapek, einem tschechischen Literaten, allerdings als Bezeichnung für einen Darsteller in einem Theaterstück, das sein Bruder geschrieben hatte..

Answer (score 1):

- Ein Japanismus ist ein aus dem Japanischen stammendes Lehn- oder Fremdwort.
- Unter Slawismus versteht man ein slawisches Wort, das den Weg in andere Sprachen gefunden hat.
- Hungarismen sind ungarische Lehnwörter.
- Skandinavismus für nordische Sprache... usw. (siehe [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehnwort#Entlehnungen_im_Deutschen))

Man findet sie natürlich auch in der einschlägigen Fachliteratur.